# escape character in variable

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I'm trying to run some code where I have a pre-existing variable.

```
// get Instance
var instanceName = 'server\instance'; // this is not accessible to me and is returned via query
var instance = new GlideRecord('cmdb_ci_db_mssql_instance');
instance.get('name', instanceName);
instance.query();
gs.print(instance.name);
gs.print(instance.sys_id);
```

Unfortunately I'm getting undefined because it's expecting the `\` to be escaped like `server\\instance`

Without access to `instanceName` how am I supposed to escape the `\`?

Comment: If you can't access it then how could you change it. There must be some way to access it.

Comment: @decpk I managed to get escape() to give me %5C I'm going to see if I can work with that.